# Unity XR hands "shaking" when XR rig moved away from initial location

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, oculusquest, unity-xr

I have a project with Unity XR and have just implemented movement of the XR rig, however I notice a very unpleasant effect: XR hands start "shaking" when the XR rig is moved away from the initial location.

Here is how it looks like:
https://youtube.com/shorts/TX6tyOfsXtQ

I made two completely independent of each other implementations of the movement: one with the locomotion system and one by just moving the rig's transform's position. Both have this shaking though.

Any idea what might have causing it and how to prevent it?
Thanks!

Comment: In my experience this is usually caused by tracking problems. Could you describe your setup and hardware a bit? What do you mean by move? Physically move? Or virtually move?

Comment: What do you mean with tracking problems, how could I solve those? Setup and hardware: Oculus Quest + Unity, simple URP project, movement is virtual only - either through locomotion or via XR Rig position update. In both cases hands are initially not shaking and the more I move away - the more they shake. If I return to the original location they stop shaking. Mega strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue is caused by floating origin inaccuracy, more details in this thread:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-xr-hands-shaking-when-xr-rig-moved-away-from-initial-location.1373310/

Fix: lock the rig at 0/0/0 and move the world instead.